# Replacing #defines constants

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am currently working on a project (in C) and we using `#defines` for default variables.
This variables are used to layout a battery buffered ram structure.

Now we have different customers that have different layouts.
In the past we would just create a whole new piece of software.
Now we are trying to get away from this fragmentation and use the same code base.

We have a general library (used across all projects) that has a set of `#define`s and declares the structures.  Currently we have a custom header file(which contains #defines for that project) and it gets compares these to `#define`s in the general library.  If different it throws an error.

We want to keep the custom header file but I am trying to find a solution for replacing the `#define`s in the general library.  One idea is to replace them with some sort of variable another is to use some sort of preprocessor define.

In the past we have used `ifdef`s but the code is really cluttered and horrible to follow so we are trying to get away from that as well.

Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have all `#define` bracketed by

```
#ifndef HUI
# define HUI 1023
#endif
```

and then place the ones that you'd like to change for an individual compile on the commandline of the compile with `-DHUI=1033`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution:
Put the defines into seperate header files.
in the Main file include the header files via #fidef

This will work if the number of diferent header is not more than a handfull.

Another solution:
seperated header files like above, but instead of selecting the includes via ifdef
put the defines into seperate folders and make a seperate make file, were the folder is added to the include path.
-> keeps the code clean but you have now  #customer makefiles